# Can't Get Form To Show in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am trying to build a form that allows users to provide a review of an area they have visited However, every iteration of trying to link the review to the beach model proves to be wasted effort.

Could someone please tell me why I can't get the form to show. I am consistently getting an error:

*Reverse for 'beaches-review' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['review/(?P<beach_id>[0-9]+)/$']*

or some variation of that.

My code is below. Thank you for any help you can provide.

**Models.py**

```
class Beach(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='beachvideo', blank=True)
    beachPic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='beachphotos', blank=True)
    datetimeInfo = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()
    info = models.TextField()

    def average_rating(self):
        all_ratings = map(lambda x: x.rating, self.review_set.all())
        return np.mean(all_ratings)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Review(models.Model):
    RATING = (
        ('1', 'Avoid'),
        ('2', 'Not Great'),
        ('3', 'Decent'),
        ('4', 'Awesome'),
        ('5', 'The Best'),
    )

    beach = models.ForeignKey(Beach, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    ratingRank = models.CharField(max_length= 100, blank=False, choices=RATING)
    waveIntensityRank = models.CharField(max_length= 100, blank=True, choices=RATING)
    crowdednessRank = models.CharField(max_length= 100, blank=True, choices=RATING)
    pollutionRank = models.CharField(max_length= 100, blank=True, choices=RATING)
    noiseLevelRank = models.CharField(max_length= 100, blank=True, choices=RATING)
    servicesRank = models.CharField(max_length= 100, blank=True, choices=RATING)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('beaches-home')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Review
        fields = ('ratingRank', 'author', 'waveIntensityRank', 'crowdednessRank', 'pollutionRank', 'noiseLevelRank', 'servicesRank', 'comments')
```

**Urls.py**

```
  urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.beachView, name='beaches-home'),
    path('beach/<int:pk>', views.beachDescription, name='beaches-description'),
    path('search/', views.searchResultsView.as_view(), name='search-results'),
    path('review/<int:beach_id>/', views.addReview, name='beaches-review'),
]
```

**Views.py**

```
def beachView(request):
    beachView = {
        'beachView': Beach.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'beaches/index.html', context = beachView)


def beachDescription(request, pk):
    beachDesc = {
        'beachDesc': Beach.objects.get(pk=pk)
    }
    return render(request, 'beaches/description.html', context = {'beachDesc': beachDesc} )


def review_list(request):
    latest_reviews = Review.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:9]



def addReview(request, beach_id):
    beachRev = get_object_or_404(Beach, pk=beach_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        review_form = ReviewForm(data=request.POST)
        if review_form.is_valid():
            rating = review_form.cleaned_data['rating']
            comment = review_form.cleaned_data['comments']
            user_name = review_form.cleaned_data['author']
            wave_intensity = review_form.cleaned_data['waveIntensityRank']
            crowds = review_form.cleaned_data['crowdednessRank']
            pollution = review_form.cleaned_data['pollutionRank']
            noise_level = review_form.cleaned_data['noiseLevelRank']
            services = review_form.cleaned_data['servicesRank']
            review = Review()
            review.beach = beachRev
            review.author = user_name
            review.rating = rating
            review.waveIntensityRank = wave_intensity
            review.crowdednessRank = crowds
            review.pollutionRank = pollution
            review.noiseLevelRank = noise_level
            review.servicesRank = services
            review.comments = comment
            review.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            review.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("beaches-description", args=(beach_id,)))
            #if request.method == "POST":
            #review_form = review_form(data=request.POST)
            #if review_form.is_valid():
            #    rating = review_form.cleaned_data
            #    post.date = timezone.now()
            #    post.save()
            #    return redirect('beaches/beachReview.html')
            #else:
            #    form=ReviewForm()

    return render(request, 'beaches/beachReview.html', context= {'review_form': review_form, 'beachRev': beachRev,})



class searchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Beach
    template_name = 'beaches/searchResults.html'

    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Beach.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(location__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bestbeach.css' %}">
</head>

<h1> {{ beachDesc.name }} </h1>
<h4> Location: {{ beachDesc.location }} </h4>
<h4> Rating: {{ beachDesc.ratingRank }} </h4>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <img src="{{ beachDesc.beachPic.url }}" width="350px" height="200px"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <video width="350px" height="200px" loop="loop" preload="auto" controls>
          <source src="{{ beachDesc.video.url }}" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video.
         </video>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h4> Information: {{ beachDesc.info }} </h4>


<a href="{% url 'beaches-review' beach_id %}">
<button class="goButton" type="submit">Leave a Review</button>
</a>


{% if review_list %}
<div>
    {% for r in review_list %}
    <div>
      <h4> Reviews: </h4>
        <p> {{ r.author }} </p>
        <h6> rated {{ r.rating }} of 5 </h6>
        <p>{{ r.comments }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% else %}
<p>No reviews are available.</p>
{% endif %}



{% endblock %}
```

Comment: <a href="{% url 'beaches-review' beach_id %}"> try ```beachDesc.beach_id```

Answer (score 0):

Just to sanitize @ha-neul's comment.

You expose a `Beach` object using the `beachDescription` view, providing the template variable `beachDesc`.

`beachDesc` now hold all the attributes of the object's model.
So to get the id you can do:

```
<a href="{% url 'beaches-review' beachDesc.id %}">
```

#### OR

```
<a href="{% url 'beaches-review' beachDesc.pk %}">
```

#### Alternatively

you could add the following method to your `Beach` model

```
def get_absolute_beach_review_url(self):
    return reverse('beaches-review', kwargs={'beach_id':self.id})
```

and link `beachDesc.get_absolute_beach_review_url` in your template.